# purrr::reduce/reduce2 or mapped mutate_at()? - functions applied to respective column

Tags: r, reduce, purrr, dplyr

I have a map of functions I want to apply to their respective columns.
Is there something liked a mapped `mutate_at`?

```
my_map <- 
  data_frame(col = names(iris)[-5],
             calc = rep(c("floor", "ceiling"), 2))
my_map 
# A tibble: 4 x 2
col          calc   
<chr>        <chr>  
Sepal.Length floor  
Sepal.Width  ceiling
Petal.Length floor  
Petal.Width  ceiling
```

Failed attempt:

```
tbl_df(iris) %>% mutate_at(vars(col_calcs$col), funs_(col_calcs$calc))

Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length_floor Sepal.Width_floor Petal.Length_floor Petal.Width_floor Sepal.Length_ceiling
      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>                <dbl>             <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>                <dbl>
       5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa                   5                 3                  1                 0                    6
       4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa                   4                 3                  1                 0                    5
```

Desired output:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
         5.0         4.0          1.0         1.0 setosa 
         4.0         3.0          1.0         1.0 setosa
```

Last thing, `my_map$calc` may have unknown functions that may be applied.
Ex) Someone can change the last "floor" to "round".

Comment: It seems like you changed your question based on the best answer you think, but it is a little bit misleading. If this is the original title, others may not submit their answers in the first place.

Comment: good point. I added back the mutate_at() in the title question. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a straight forward way to do this with `dplyr::mutate_*` function; One work around is to use the `reduce` (or `reduce2`) function and mutate column with the corresponding transform function one by one:

```
library(tidyverse)

reduce2(.x = my_map$col, 
        .y = my_map$calc, 
        .f = function(df, col, f) mutate_at(df, vars(col), f), 
        .init = iris) %>% head(2)

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1            5           4            1           1  setosa
# 2            4           3            1           1  setosa
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to use `map2` to replace each column.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris2 <- iris

iris2[, -5] <- map2(my_map$calc, my_map$col, function(x, y){
  x2 <- eval(parse(text = x))
  y2 <- iris2[[y]]
  result <- x2(y2)
  return(result)
})

head(iris2)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1            5           4            1           1  setosa
# 2            4           3            1           1  setosa
# 3            4           4            1           1  setosa
# 4            4           4            1           1  setosa
# 5            5           4            1           1  setosa
# 6            5           4            1           1  setosa
```

Comment: We can simplify this a little, first you can use `get(x)` instead of `eval(parse(text=x))`, then we can notice that we can use `mget`, which is a vectorized version of `get` with different defaults, and we can use it directly in the `map2` call, finally we can use the short formula notation to be a little more compact, and we obtain:  `iris2[-5] <- map2(mget(my_map$calc,inherits =TRUE), my_map$col, ~ .x(iris[[.y]]))`.  This can easily transform into a neat base solution : `iris2[-5] <- Map(function(x, y) x(iris[[y]]), mget(my_map$calc,inherits =TRUE), my_map$col)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for sharing your nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

We could start from `my_map` :

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(my_map$col,my_map$calc,~transmute_at(iris,.x,.y)) %>%
  bind_cols(iris[!names(iris) %in% my_map$col]) %>% # or less general: iris[-5]  
  head

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1            5           4            1           1  setosa
# 2            4           3            1           1  setosa
# 3            4           4            1           1  setosa
# 4            4           4            1           1  setosa
# 5            5           4            1           1  setosa
# 6            5           4            1           1  setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that all variables, which you want to take the `floor` function, contain the same character, i.e. `Length`, and all variables, which you want to take the `ceiling` function, contain the same character, i.e. `Width`, then we can apply the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Length")), funs(floor)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Width")), funs(ceiling))

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1            5           4            1           1  setosa
# 2            4           3            1           1  setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

Although verbose, I find the following very readable and a simple implementation of map:

```
iris2 <- iris %>% 
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
    gather(key = col, value, my_map$col ) %>%
    full_join(my_map, by = "col") %>%
    mutate(value = invoke_map(.f = calc, .x = value)) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    select(-calc) %>
    spread(col, value) %>%
    select(-id)

head(iris2)
#    Species Petal.Length Petal.Width Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1  setosa            1           1            5           4
# 2  setosa            1           1            4           3
# 3  setosa            1           1            4           4
# 4  setosa            1           1            4           4
# 5  setosa            1           1            5           4
```